# Operating gnu octave through a Java program

Tags: java, linux, octave

I want to operate octave through a Java program.

I've been implementing a java program where I'm using the 'Process' class to communicate with GNU Octave. I have:

1. Two InputStreamReader variables (one for getting output of valid commands from Octave, and the other for getting errors).
2. An OutputStreamWriter variable for giving commands to Octave.

I've implemented a mechanism where commands can be given from the java program to Octave and the result can be received in the java program properly.

The problem happens when there are errors in the command given to Octave. I read the error from the error stream and print it. This happens properly **for once**. But after this, if I try to give another command to Octave through my OutputStreamWriter variable, it says 'Broken pipe'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [commons exec][1]? It is a well known library that really helps managing external programs. It helped me managing external programs from java in a Linux environment.

[1]: http://commons.apache.org/exec/"commons exec"

Comment: I don't find much of documentation of 'commons exec' with respect to linux. I'm better at using the 'Process' class. Thanks, will try it out and see. :-)

Comment: Give it a try...the tutorial is good enough, and it is really hard to make Process work as it is supposed to.

Comment: Figured out the error myself :-) Octave exits if it receives an erroraneous command. I have to run it with the '-i' option, to let it run even after a wrong command is issued.